# No ntp.conf file after compiling ntp on Linux

Tags: linux, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, ntp

I'm using RHEL 6.5. I compiled ntp-4.2.8 using the steps [on this link](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/ntp.html).

but I don't have a `ntp.conf` file. `ntp.conf` is required to start ntpd but after compiling, there is no ntp.conf on my system. I found `ntp.conf.texi`, `ntp.conf.5`, `ntp.conf.def`, `ntp.conf.html` etc.

Executing command `ntpd -l logg` I get an error in `logg` file:

```
getconfig: Couldn't open </etc/ntp.conf>
```

I am using same `./configure` command as on this link. How can I generate `ntp.conf`?

Comment: What do you mean, specifically, by "not able"? `./configure` has nothing to do with `ntp.conf`. `./configure` is used to prepare the binary for compilation. How far did you get? At which step are you stuck?

Comment: net.conf is required to start ntpd but after compiling and installing latest ntp I am not able to find ntp.conf on my system. I find ntp.conf.texi, ntp.conf.5, ntp.conf.def, ntp.conf.html etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're supposed to create the file yourself. It's in the tutorial, where it says:

```
cat > /etc/ntp.conf << "EOF"
# Asia
server 0.asia.pool.ntp.org

# Australia
server 0.oceania.pool.ntp.org

# Europe
server 0.europe.pool.ntp.org

# North America
server 0.north-america.pool.ntp.org

# South America
server 2.south-america.pool.ntp.org

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
pidfile   /var/run/ntpd.pid
EOF
```

That entire command will create your configuration file. Of course, you may want to edit the file and only select the servers that are relevant for the region you're in.

Comment: how to add this ntp in services, so it gets started automatically; When I install ntp rpm from RHEL iso it gets automatically started, I can see the entry in **init.d** . Tried using **chkconfig --add ntpd** it returns error: **error reading information on service ntpd: No such file or directory**

Comment: The tutorial has instructions on how to set it up to run at boot. I'm not at a computer right now so I can't look at how to use `chkconfig` for that, sorry.